# Sort Array with Kendo UI Sortable and Angular

Tags: angularjs, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-sortable

I am using Kendo UI with Angular and Typescript. I know Kendo UI and Angular is a pain, but I have to do it like that...

The view works great, but when I want to access the array in the change-Event and reorder the array the variable doesn't exists. It seems that this is another scope. So in this demo the alert will pop up:

```
        // Change Event
        changed(e: kendo.ui.SortableEndEvent) {
          console.log(e);
          console.info(this.data);

          // For Demo
          if(this.data == undefined){
            alert("Can not access Data Array");
            return;
          }

            // swap
            var oldElement = this.data[e.oldIndex];
            this.data[e.oldIndex] = this.data[e.newIndex];
            this.data[e.newIndex] = oldElement;
        }

         data = [
          { value: "Val 1" },
          { value: "Val 2"},
          { value: "Value 3"},
          { value: "Value 4"}
        ];
```

Is there a workaround, so I can access the array?

I have a example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozbRJA?editors=1010

Comment: The `change` event is most likely called in the context of the `Sortable` widget. Something like `this.$angular_scope.ctrl.data` might work. I cannot verify it right now unfortunately.

Comment: It works like a charm! In my mainproject I had even to do `this.$angular_scope.$parent.ctrl.data`, but that's okay. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Philipp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1648800/philipp) commented, the change event is in another context. With `this.$angular_scope.ctrl.data` I can access the controller scope and the array. It's not very beautiful, but it works.